# What groups only have groups as members

Tags: powershell

I tried to ask this before but I didn't give enough information. Here is my 2nd attempt.

I have around 2k groups and each group has various members amounts from 1 entry to many.

I want to find which of the the 2k groups only have another group as a member.

I can make a command that will tell me all groups, their members and each member type

I can use a foreach to go through the groups but were I am getting stuck is how do I foreach one group and know all the members types are only groups?

I need an answer telling me how to pull what I need from an array that holds all the groups, their members and what type of entry it is.

When I do my pull it is from Google and not AD. There is not a Google API command like get-aduser that will help me with my problem.

example code

```
$ALLGROUPS_MEMBERS_AND_TYPE = gam print group-members fields type | ConvertFrom-Csv

$ALLGROUPS_MEMBERS_AND_TYPE = $ALLGROUPS_MEMBERS_AND_TYPE | Sort-Object -Property group

$ALLGROUPS_MEMBERS_AND_TYPE | Get-Member 

TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
group       NoteProperty string group=Email@domain.com
type        NoteProperty string type=USER
```

The array looks like

```
Email                                Type
Email@domain.com                     USER
Email2@domain.com                    USER
Email3domain.com                     USER
DifferentEmail@domain.com            GROUP
DifferentEmail1@domain.com           USER
DifferentEmail2@domain.com           USER
etc...
```

I know I am going to need some kind of loop like this but I have no idea how to loop through and find out which group only has groups as members.

```
$results = $ALLGROUPS_MEMBERS_AND_TYPE | ForEach-Object {

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Email = $_.group
        Type  = $_.type
    }
}
```

**===================
UPDATE BELOW**

I realized in the comments that "I think I need to add another command this command `$ALLGROUPS_MEMBERS_AND_TYPE = gam print group-members fields type | ConvertFrom-Csv`  only tells me all groups, their members and each type it does not tell me which member is a member of which group it simply tells me everything in all groups. I need a list to compare to"

so I made this

```
$AllGroupMembers = gam print groups members notsuspended domain sonos.com | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Which gives me all groups and there members but not the member type

Now I know I need to compare for type. I am still not sure how to only include a group that only has groups as members.

I think it will go something like this but this doesn't work.

```
$results = $ALLGROUPS_MEMBERS_AND_TYPE | Where-Object { $_.Type -eq 'group'-and $AllGroupMembers.members -notcontains $_.group }
```

Comment: Something like `$results = $ALLGROUPS_MEMBERS_AND_TYPE | Where-Object { $_.Type -eq 'group'}` perhaps?

Comment: That would give me all groups. Not a bad idea then I can bring it to a spreadsheet and go from there. @Theo

Comment: the logic I would follow would be the same as with the AD module, tho I don't know about the google API, first get all groups, then for each group get their membership and exclude the group if it has a member other than `group` (assuming I understood the problem correctly)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I can get all all the groups and there membership.
How could I refine the pull or a loop to as you wrote?

Comment: I think I need to add another command this command ```$ALLGROUPS_MEMBERS_AND_TYPE = gam print group-members fields type | ConvertFrom-Csv``` only tells me all groups, their members and each type it does not tell me which member is a member of which group it simply tells me everything in all groups.

I need a list to compare to.

Comment: Unfortunately cant help you that much but, `gam print groups` (get only groups here no need to query members), then, for each group query it's membership (`gam print group-members 'thisgrouphere?'`) and check if the membership has any other object than `group`.